# MVC PHP - Libraries - Estrutura de Diretórios

Tags: php, mvc

estou com uma dúvida em relação da estrutura de pasta da aplicação.

Seguinte, a dúvida surge quando há a necessidade de escrever uma classe que faz integração com um **API** essa classe seria alocada em que parte? Pois creio que essa classe não teria comportamento de uma componente (não tem qualquer tipo de logica de negócio) e sim talvez de uma **lib** (Library) que seria uma interface para consumir os recursos da API.

Imaginem a seguinte estrutura:

```
/app/
 - controllers/
 - components/
 - models/
 - vendors/
```

Mas a questão é, se **API** é um pacote escrito por mim, ela não deveria ir para **vendors** (já que vendors são só para pacotes de terceiros), estou certo? Ou talvez seria ideal ter uma novo diretório ***librarys/*** para pacotes internos da aplicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em casos como esse a organização é feita da seguinte forma: `/vendors/Company/Library/Company/PackageName`. Se seu código é genérico e poderá ser reutilizado em outros projetos sem muita necessidade de adaptação, ou seja, como você mesmo disse, se não tem nenhuma regra de negócio, o lugar dele é na `vendors`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @hamboldt, entendo, sendo assim posso empacotar todas as classes que não tem logica com da aplicação mas que são utilizas pelo mesmo, em um pacote próprio dentro de `vendors`?

Comment: Exatamente. Quando vamos fazer um software temos que pensar como iremos fazer para que este tenha a maior possibilidade de ter partes reaproveitáveis. Então se conseguirmos separar coisas reaproveitáveis dos códigos específicos de regra de negócio significa que iremos ter cada vez menos trabalho futuramente, podendo reutilizar sem muito esforço nossos códigos passados.

É importante ter em mente também que devemos organizar de modo que podemos presumir onde cada coisa está por exemplo:

* /library/Outlook/Email/Author.php 
* /library/Outlook/SMTP/Request.php
* /library/Outlook/SMTP/Response...

Answer (score 1):

A minha resposta vai no sentido da minha experiência em MVC e especificamente em PHP conforme colocado na pergunta e no que diz respeito à sua estrutura.

Sem entrar em conceitos básicos, a experiência levou-me ao longo dos anos a adoptar uma estrutura diferente daquela que apresenta no entanto sei bem que esta depende muito de caso para caso. Para um projecto que implemente também uma api em conjunto:

```
/projecto/
   |--api/
   |    |--resources/
   |    |index.php
   |    |.htaccess
   |
   |--application/
   |    |--config/
   |    |--controllers/
   |    |--models/
   |    |--libraries/
   |    |--views/
   |    |--(etc... dentro da lógica)
   |    |.htaccess (deny from all)
   | 
   |--public/
   |--vendor/
   |
   |index.php
   |.htaccess
```

Como pode observar o `models` fica dentro do `application` e não fora o seu `components` penso que será equivalente ao `libraries` e quanto ao `vendors` a norma é chamar-lhe `vendor` no singular caso trabalhe com o Composer... dá mais jeito.

O `.htaccess` é colocado em cada directório que esteja na raiz do projecto e aí entra a minha resposta directa à sua pergunta sobre o `API`. Tratando-se de um serviço adicional ao projecto normalmente incluo o directório `API na raíz` e com o referido `.htaccess`, desta forma defende os recursos lá presentes por via de uma **url amigável**.

Recordo que um MVC separa o layout do código PHP e no que respeita ao API deve de separar a implementação de recursos da lógica dos models que por questões de manutenção do código deve de utilizar as implementações em `application/models`, neste caso :)

Comment: Obrigado por responder @chambelix, mas neste casso eu não estaria gerando redundância já que minha intenção na verdade não é disponibilizar uma `API` e sim a 'classe' de `API` na verdade estará buscando informações de uma API de terceiros. Estou correto, que não seria uma boa?